# get text inside list item jquery not working on chrome & ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer

i have this simple html markup i am trying to create custom select dropdown from

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6 select">
    <label for="">Accounts</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="acc_reports" readonly placeholder="select an account">
    <ul class="acc_reports">
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

i am trying to get the text inside the clicked list item and put it as a value for the input field through this javascript code

```
var options = $('.select>ul>li');
options.click(function() {
 var value = $(this).text();
 var optClass = $(this).parent().attr('class');
 var select = $('#' + optClass);
 select.attr('value', value);
});
```

it is working fine on firefox but not working on chrome and ie, working on some list items and not working on others .i am not getting any errors

EDIT:
i am running another js code on the input it self to trigger the list , i tried to create a fiddle but somehow it is not working on the fiddle , but this block of code working fine on all browsers . but i updated the question because it may have something to do with my problem.

```
input = $('.select>input');

input.focusin(function() {
inputIdIn = $(this).attr('id');
CstSelectIn(inputIdIn);

});

input.focusout(function() {
inputIdOut = $(this).attr('id');
CstSelectOut(inputIdOut);

});

function CstSelectIn (inputIdIn) {
dropdownIn = $('.' + inputIdIn);
ddHeightIn = dropdownIn.height() + 'px';
    dropdownIn.css({
    height: '0',
    display: 'block'
    }).animate({
        height: ddHeightIn
    }, 400, 'easeOutExpo');
};
function CstSelectOut (inputIdOut) {
dropdownOut = $('.' + inputIdOut);
dropdownOut.animate({
    height: '0'
}, 400, 'easeOutExpo', function() {
    dropdownOut.css({
        display: 'none',
        height: 'auto'
    });
});
};
```

EDIT2: i commented out the `focusIn()` and `focusOut()` functions and it worked , i have been trying to debug the issue but still can not figure it out . there is some kind of conflict these functions making on chrome and ie stopping the select from working

Comment: You should probably be using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

Comment: same result , weird thing is in both ways its working on the first 2 list items only. and when i use @CBroe answer it works on thr first 3 items only

Answer (score 1):

Chrome seems to take the `readonly` of the input field to mean “don’t let it be updated via script either”. (IE I couln’t test right now, but I’d assume it fails in there for the same reason.)

Solution: Remove `readonly` temporarily (by setting it to false), set the new value, and make it readonly again:

```
select.attr('readonly', false).attr('value', value).attr('readonly', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ae9bmw0z/

Comment: still same problem , i removed the readonly attr and tried still not working right . i think it has something else to do maybe with getting the text insde the list item from the first place. (p.s i edited the question to explain more how it works on chrome and ie)

Comment: Is that jsfiddle example I posted not working for you, not even in Chrome? Then please show a live example of your actual code, where we can see the problem.

Comment: i tried to create a fiddle with all the code but the trigger list functions not working on the fiddle so i had to post it here , these all the js im running on the input or the list items , thanks i appreciate your help , and your fiddle working great this is why i am now wondring whats wrong with my code .. i am still a js beginner so i am expecting some issues in my code that i do not notice

Comment: i commented out the `focusIn()` and `focusOut()` functions i had on the input fields and it is working , so i guess something in these two functions making a conflict i am trying to debug and see whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

i tried another approach for this custom select menu , by using `.click()` not focus functions and it worked , looks like there is some confusion in chrome and ie on applying the focusout function and running the select function maybe this conflict coming from setting the list to `display: none;` on the focusout function.